# Why "=" is not possible for the "add" function in "set" object in python?

Tags: python

in `python`, `add` is used to add items to a `set` object:

```
set_object = {'apple', 'orange'}
set_object.add('pear')
```

However, `new_object = set_object.add('pear')` is not equivalent to `set_object.add('pear')`.

So why is that, and is there an equivalent way to assign the `new_object` to a variable? What I should do if I do not want to modify the original `set_object`?

This also does not work

```
new_object = set_object + {'pear'}
```

Currently, it seems that I have to do:

```
set_object = {'apple', 'orange'}
set_object.add('pear')
new_object = set_object
set_object = {'apple', 'orange'}
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: What do you expect to be in `new_object`? its a reference to the same set, it isn't a copy

Comment: It's not equivalent, because you are binding new_object to the result of calling add (the object returned by add) - which is None. The add method is meant to be used in-place.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns is a great talk on references in python which might help clear up a few things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `union` function  or `'|'` operator to append new `set` to the existing one.

```
set_object = {'apple', 'orange'}
new_object = set_object | {'pear'}
```

or

```
set_object = {'apple', 'orange'}
new_object = set_object.union({'pear'})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not about `set`. If you do as below, you would get `None` value again.

```
a = [1, 2]
b = a.append(3)
print(b)
# None
```

That's why you would get `None`, when you do like:

```
new_object = set_object.add('pear')
print(new_object)
# None
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply using the wrong operator. `+` is not defined for sets; `|` is.

```
new_object = set_object | {'pear'}
```